docker-compose command execute on local dev but not in prod
I'm using this docker-compose file
app:
  image: app_image
  container_name: myapp_app
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: _docker/app.Dockerfile
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
    - ./vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
  tty: true
  environment:
    COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: myapp-php
  networks:
    - laravel
  entrypoint: bash -c "composer install --ignore-platform-reqs"

nginx:
  image: app_image
  container_name: myapp_nginx
  volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
    - ./vendor:/var/www/html/vendor
  tty: true
  ports:
    - 80:80
  environment:
    START_NGINX: 1
    COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: myapp-php
  networks:
    - laravel
  restart: unless-stopped
  depends_on:
    - app

gulp:
  container_name: myapp_gulp
  build:
    context: .
    dockerfile: _docker/gulp.Dockerfile
  tty: true
  volumes:
    - ./_metronic:/var/www/html/_metronic
    - ./public:/var/www/html/public
    - ./resources:/var/www/html/resources
  environment:
    COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME: myapp-php
  networks:
    - laravel
  command: bash -c "cd tools && yarn install && gulp"

With this Dockerfile
FROM public.ecr.aws/ubuntu/ubuntu:18.04_stable
...
WORKDIR /var/www/html/_metronic
COPY ./_metronic /var/www/html/_metronic

RUN npm i -y node-sass@^4.14.0
RUN npm rebuild node-sass

RUN npm i -y -g gulp@3.9.1 --allow-root
RUN npm i -y    gulp@3.9.1 --allow-root
RUN npm link gulp

RUN npm i -g yarn --allow-root

So I run this command in my computer:
docker-compose up --build gulp

It works, shows the output fine and creates neccessary directories like node_modules.
On prod environment (amazon linux 2023) I run the same command but with -d argument.
docker-compose up -d --build gulp

So it doesn't show docker-compose command output and, like that line didn't exists and don't create the node_modules directory.
That command seems to be not running.
Am I missing something?

Have you tried running this command docker-compose up -d --build gulp without the -d to check the output in amazon linux 2023?

What's the default CMD the image should run?  Why are you reinstalling modules every time the container starts up, instead of RUN yarn install once in the Dockerfile?

@DavidMaze thanks for the comment. If I run yarn install on Dockerfile it doesn't create the node_modules dir on host machine to share it with other services

The node_modules tree shouldn't be shared with other services, most likely.  Each service's Dockerfile should have its own RUN npm install line, and each image will have its own isolated library tree that can be independently updated.  The library tree doesn't need to exist on the host outside an image.

I've added the other services to question code. It builds the image on app service and share it to nginx and gulp services. That's why my thoughts are on sharing files between all of them, so nginx provide the webserver with app original files and front-end compiled by gulp service. Is this the correct way to achive this?
